# Return multiple middleware funcs from router.HandleFunc call

Tags: go, gorilla

I am using gorilla/mux I have this:

```
router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/register",h.makeRegisterNewUser(v)).Methods("POST")
```

and `h.makeRegisterNewUser` looks like:

```
func (h Handler) makeRegisterNewUser(v interface{}) http.HandlerFunc {

    type RespBody = ...;
    type ReqBody = ...


    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
        err := decoder.Decode(&ReqBody)

        // ...

        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(RespBody{});
    }
}
```

my question is - is there a way to return multiple http.HandlerFuncs from makeRegisterNewUser? Something like this:

```
router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/register",h.makeRegisterNewUser(v)).Methods("POST")

func (h Handler) makeRegisterNewUser(v interface{}) (http.HandlerFunc...) {

    type RespBody = ...;
    type ReqBody = ...


    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       // 1

    }, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       // 2

    }, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // 3
    }
}
```

I am not sure if middleware can be chained in Go like it does in Node.js Express.

Comment: Can you please update your question and explain why you need 3 functions for one route?

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski so the the middleware funcs are associated - 1,2,3 are called in that order (serially) for the request. For example 1 and 2 could to write "res.headers" and 3 could write to "res.body", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain multiple `http.Handler` using wrapper:

```
type Middleware struct {
    next          http.Handler
}

func (m Middleware) Wrap(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    m.next = handler
    return m
}

func (m Middleware) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // run your handler code here
    // write error into w and return if you need to interrupt request execution

    // call next handler 
    m.next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Register chained wrappers and main handler:

```
h1 := Middleware{}
h2 := OtherMiddleware{}
router.Handle("/some_route", h1.Wrap(h2.Wrap(mainHandler))).Methods(http.MethodPost)
```

Request will execute `h1`, `h2` and finally `mainHandler`.

For example, you can log request in `h1`, authorize in `h2` and keep business logic in `mainHandler`.

Comment: very nice, ty, will accept if nothing better shows up in the next day or two!

Comment: toward the bottom in your example, is it `router.Handle()` or should it be `router.HandleFunc()`? Just want to be clear, I think it should be the latter, might be a typo, thanks.

Comment: in my sample it should be `router.Handle()` because we use struct that implements `http.Handler`. `router.HandleFunc()` requires `func()` as argument.